# Discount C++ program using a switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

so basically im trying to do a small program that let the user enter a value then if the value equal or greater than x make discount something like 12%
here is an example

```
15% discount, if sales are greater than or equal to 1000
10% discount, if sales are greater than or equal to 500
5% discount, if sales are greater than or equal to 250
0, otherwise.
```

i know how to do it using if statement, but in switch i have no idea, there could be million cases about the entered value, so i need help if its possible

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use a switch? What should be the argument of the switch?

Comment: You can't do multiple *is greater then or equal* in a switch. Sounds like the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be

```
int sales; // ToDo - needs a value
double discount;
switch (std::max(sales / 250, 4)){
case 4:
    discount = 0.15;
    break;
case 3: case 2:
    discount = 0.10;
    break;
case 1:
    discount = 0.05;
    break;
default:
    discount = 0.0;
}
```

but just because it's possible doesn't mean it's the right thing to do. It most certainly is not. My solution would be a pain in the neck to tweak if the thresholds change - that is poor program design indeed since you don't really want to have to change the program control flow if parameters change.

Use an `if` block, or some kind of data structure.

Comment: i was thinking the same thing but my professor asked us to do an assignment as the following picture https://imgur.com/G6Q3HOT

im just trying to figure it out if it was possible